# Trying to get Monthly Sales Volume SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

I am trying to find AVERAGE monthly sales volumes in order to find monthly revenue (avg price * avg volume sold per month) to complete a market basket analysis using adventureworks2019.  an example of how it looks in powerbi is below.  I have already found the average prices and filled in item_price and item2_price columns with the use of the lookupvalue function.  In theory, I want two more columns, one with monthly Sales volume for item, the other for item 2.

[image]

Table of results for above query:

[image]

I am using this formula

```
SELECT
PP.[Name] ProductName,
SUM(SSOD.[OrderQty]) AS Vol_Sold,
AVG(SSOD.[LineTotal]/SSOD.[OrderQty]) AS Avg_Price

FROM
[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] AS SSOD
LEFT JOIN [Production].[Product] AS PP
ON SSOD.[ProductID] = PP.[ProductID]
LEFT JOIN [Production].[ProductSubCategory] AS PPSC
ON PPSC.[ProductSubCategoryID] = PP.[ProductSubCategoryID]
LEFT JOIN [Production].[ProductCategory] AS PPC
ON PPC.[ProductCategoryID] = PPSC.[ProductCategoryID]
LEFT JOIN [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] AS SSOH
ON SSOH.[SalesOrderID] = SSOD.[SalesOrderID]

WHERE SSOH.[OnlineOrderFlag] = 1

GROUP BY PP.[Name]
ORDER BY PP.[Name]
```

I have access to 'OrderDate', and can format this by 'MM-yyyy' but am not sure what to be doing next.

Could anyone assist?

Thanks

Comment: Average monthly sales volumes of *what*?  Sample data and desired results are helpful.

Comment: Sorry.  Average monthly sales volume of each product (PP.[Name] - ProductName).  I posted another screenshot of the table resulting from the query.  I have the sales volume for each of the ProductNames, but am wondering how I can go and categorise these as monthly.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is item2? What are you missing? What does your expected output look like?